# Kill the child process after reaching a certain time

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I have this code here, which is to execute a program multiple times in different process through parallel or sequential. After a certain time, I will need to kill all the child to stop the program.

But whenever I tried to kill the child, the child that is currently executing this line, execvp(cmdTokens[0], cmdTokens);, will not stop until it finished. It seems like it kills the loop, but not the child that is currently running.

Comment: `cid` is uninitialized on the first call to `waitpid()` — that is not a good idea.  You should probably check its return value too.  It would be conventional to exit with a non-zero value on failure to execute; it is also a good idea to report errors on the standard error channel, not standard output. Your logic from `alarm()` is dubious; `alarm()` sets a future signal to occur, in general, and returns promptly. You should probably be setting a SIGALRM handler, and doing the `waitpid()` after setting the alarm, checking for EINTR (which indicate the timeout occurring, probably) or child dying.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know how the alarm function works until you tell me. What I did was reposition the alarm method to the top so it can sets a future signal as you said.

Answer (score 1):

The exec class of functions will never return if they are successful. They essentially transform your process into the thing you are calling. This is why you fork before calling exec assuming you want to keep your original process running. They can return if they fail to start the process (like for file not found for instance).